# Average of digits in Armstrong numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a proof (other than examinining all Armstrong numbers) that given a base 10 Armstrong number N (non trivial - at least three digits long), the average of 
of it's digits $a(N)$ satisfies:  $3 \le  a(N)  \le 6$  ?

Comment: Most large numbers satisfy this because the average of all the digits is $4.5$.  You nee a lot of big ones or a lot of small ones to violate it. This says nothing about the special properties of Armstrong numbers.

Comment: My intuition (which may be wrong) is that if the average is too low ( too high ) the power sum of the digits will be too small (great) relative to their base 10 expansion

Comment: I don't think you can get there because the low order digit could (in theory) all be $1$'s without changing the magnitude much at all.

Comment: This is the kind of example I had in mind, for {1,1,1...,1} we will have the power sum of $N$ on one side and ~ $10^N$ on the other.

Comment: Yes, but if you have a few other digits high in the number it is hard to rule out.

Comment: True, but then the average start to creep up.